# PhoneGap screen sizes support

Tags: iphone, android, html, cordova

I am starting a project with PhoneGap and it will work on iPhone and Android devices. The question is how to implement support for different screen sizes and resolutions.

For example, I have an icon inside the application: small waves to run some action. What size of this icon should be to be shown well in all possible devices (iPhones/Androids). Should I include several versions of the same image?

The same question about text. How can I be sure the text will be readable and will stay in line on different devices?

thank you

Comment: In iOS you should use 2 set of icons for best user experience, one for retina and one for older, lower resolutions screens. Image resolution for retina display is exactly width*2 x height*2 of regular image you would use for low res screens. The best thing is iOS manages images in that context automatically, only requirement being images for retina display bear @2x suffix. For instance image.jpg and image@2x.jpg. Not sure about Android...

Answer (score 2):

If you are a MAC user you could give the new dreamweaver 5.5 a shot.  It will structure your app and even build a debug version for testing.  You can do this with either the ANDROID SDK or the iOS sdk.  Of course, it will work on a PC as well but there is not support for the iOS sdk.

Using the Adobe Dreamweaver 5.5 it has specific mobile framework to recognize jqm or jqtouch and inserts phonegap.js on build into the packaged product.  It also allows you to scale the testing screen for the different sizes of mobile devices.  From android, iphone, to ipad(and more)
Here is an example:  [Dreamweaver with phonegap support](http://www.leonardofranca.com/index.php/2011/05/02/creating-mobile-applications-with-dreamweaver-cs-5-5-and-phonegap/)